# iframe не обновляется при изменении значения src

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

На сколько я знаю, чтобы обновить содержимое iframe достаточно просто обновить значение в src. Но у меня почему-то ничего не обновляется. Я вырезал из кода все лишнее, чтобы просто показать, что оно не работает.

Тут просто строка, в которую если ничего не вводить, будет сайт с надписью, что ничего и не введено, если ввести рандомные цифры, то будет черный экран. Но вот если сначала ввести одно, а потом другое, то страница не обновится. Специально еще добавил текст, который показывает то, что написано непосредственно в значении src, чтобы убедиться, что оно не меняется.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    
    <script>
        function BlurInp() {
            var url = "https://kirlovon.dev/Kinopoisk-Watch/#/" + document.getElementById("srchInput").value;
            //UPD ↓
            document.getElementById("film").src = "";
            //        ↑
            document.getElementById("film").src = url;

            document.getElementById("text").innerHTML = document.getElementById("film").src;
        }
    </script>


</head>

<body>
<input type="text" id="srchInput">
   
    <button id="toggle" onclick="BlurInp()">on</button>
      <div id=text>URL</div>
    <iframe allow="fullscreen" src="" width="1280px" height="720px" id="film"></iframe>

</body></html>
```

Comment: Ваш новый url отличается от старого только хэшем — значением после символа #. Это означает, что вы всего лишь запросили прокрутку до указанного после # элемента на текущем url, поэтому страница обновляться не должна. Вместо этого на страницу отправляется событие hashchange

Comment: Хмм, интересно. Тогда может стоит сначала сделать переход на любую рандомную ссылку, а потом на нужный сайт. Попробую

Comment: Рааабооотаеть